# Creating a comples form in html

Tags: html, css

i'm making a html form from a pdf file. Attached is a screenshot

[image]

The input fields was different width. Is there a better way to do this form using css or jquery for the width.

Here is my fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/amW5c/

```
<p>
   <label class="lbl1">Name: (as it appears on passport):</label>
   <input name="" type="text" class="inpt1" />
</p>
<p>
    <label class="lbl1">Address:</label>
    <input name="" type="text" class="inpt1" /> 
    <label class="lbl1">Apt.#:</label>
    <input name="" type="text" class="inpt1" />
 </p>
 <p>
    <label class="lbl1">City:</label>
    <input name="" type="text" class="inpt1" />    
    <label class="lbl1">State:</label>
    <input name="" type="text" class="inpt1" />
    <label class="lbl1">Zip:</label>
    <input name="" type="text" class="inpt1" />
 </p>
```

Thanks

San

Comment: You mean this: `<input name="" type="text" style="width: 300px" />`?

Comment: Give the input a class or id and then style it in css..

Comment: Yeah I know this, but then I have to create css for every input box. Just wanted to know if there is a smart way to fit the width?

Comment: css for every input box?? input{width:300px;}

Comment: My every input box has a different width

Comment: In that case use css inline as @solusipse suggested or with a class. Usually I put my forms inside a html table and define columns width but in your case I don't think that will help you.

Comment: how can my input box occupy the empty space as giving 100% width throws it on the next line